# Paypal Checkout with a Product_Id

Tags: javascript, web, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently using the [Smart Checkout Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/) from Paypal to purchase Customer.

I'm also listening for Webhook Notification.

Everything is working fine, but my problem is that I have multiple products the User can buy. So I need to get an information about the product in my Webhook.

Is there any way to create products in Paypal like in Stripe or to put some extra values like product id  to the Checkout, so that I know which product the user bought.

I tried it with some fields like "item" below, but I could'nt access them inside my webhook.

```
  var button = paypal.Buttons({
    fundingSource: fundingSource,
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
  return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'EUR',
        value: '0.69'
      },
      item:"product_id12345"
    }]
  });
}
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid fields like "item" will simply be ignored, so you need a properly formatted items array and pricing breakdown, per the Orders V2 API specification.  You can find a long example in the `purchase_units` [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#on-the-server)

There is no reason your server should be waiting for dubiously reliable asynchronous webhooks to be notified of successful transactions and the item information in them. Instead, switch to a robust server integration. Here is the front-end UI to use: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

All the product/cart information your server needs can be communicated in those fetch calls to it, and in its Orders API calls to PayPal (in the items array and required amount breakdown parameters you can add once you get everything else working), immediately. It's far better than waiting around for a webhook.